# CSS Grid hover effect on Child Element not working

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, css-grid

i'm trying to achieve an overlay hover effect on a specific child element thats inside a css grid, but it's not working.

I've tried the same code on a separate div, and it worked just fine, and when I'm using the chrome dev tools to activate the hover effect, it is in fact working, but when i'm trying to hover on it with just my mouse, it's not.

The element i'm trying to add an overlay to is the .item3, .item6, .item8 class.

Hoping someone can help me out.

Here is my code:

```css
.item1 { 
  grid-area: first;
  height: 391px; 
  background-image: url("https://magicezy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/simple-reliable-innovatice-banner-2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.item2 { 
  grid-area: second; 
  height: 92px;
  background-image: url("https://magicezy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/texture-1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.item3 { 
  grid-area: third; 
  background-image: url("https://magicezy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Lifestyle-2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.item4 { grid-area: fourth; }
.item5 { grid-area: fifth; }
.item6 { 
  grid-area: sixth; 
  background-image: url("https://magicezy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Home-and-Living-2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.item7 { grid-area: seventh; }
.item8 { 
  grid-area: eight;
  background-image: url("https://magicezy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Cars-and-Boats-1-1.jpg");
  background-size: cover; 
}

.item3, .item4{ 
  height: 299px;
}

.item5, .item6, .item7, .item8{ 
  height: 391px;
}

.grid-container {
  font-family: 'roboto', 'sens-serif';
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'first first second second'
    'first first second second'
    'first first third fourth'
    'fifth sixth seventh eight';
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 19.7% 30.3%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.home-category-title
{
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 750;
}

.home-category-content
{
    font-size: 18.5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.item3 {
  position: relative;
}

.home-category-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.grid-container .item-3:hover .home-category-overlay {
  opacity: .5;
}

.item3:hover .home-category-overlay {
  opacity: .5;
}

.home-category-content-overlay {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 22%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item1">
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
            <div class="home-category-overlay">
                <div class="home-category-content-overlay">Lifestyle</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item4">
            <h3 class="home-category-title">LIFESTYLE</h3>
            <div class="home-category-content">
                Uncover the latest technology that perfectly blends with your everyday needs. May it be DIY scratch
                repairs or future innovations.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item5">
            <h3 class="home-category-title">HOME & LIVING</h3>
            <div class="home-category-content">
                Wonder in awe of MagicEzy’s surface repair kits made to make DIY floor, tile, appearance, or even
                kitchen & bathroom repairs look pro
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item6">
            <div class="home-category-overlay">
                <div class="home-category-content-overlay">Home & Living</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item7">
            <h3 class="home-category-title">CARS & <p>BOATS</h3>
            <div class="home-category-content">
                Explore MagicEzy’s top of the line DIY scratch removers, non-drip paint chip repair kits, fiberglass and
                gelcoat boat repair kit ready to sail & journey with you
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item8">
            <div class="home-category-overlay">
                <div class="home-category-content-overlay">Cars & Boats</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try to add
`z-index: 10; position:relative` to .item3, .item6, and .item8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `position:relative` to all div item like this `.grid-container > div {position:relative}` or just in `.item6` and `.item8` in this div otherwise `position: absolute;` div overlay each other also add hover css for  `.item6` and `.item8`

```css
.item1 { 
  grid-area: first;
  height: 391px; 
  background-image: url("https://magicezy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/simple-reliable-innovatice-banner-2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.item2 { 
  grid-area: second; 
  height: 92px;
  background-image: url("https://magicezy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/texture-1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.item3 { 
  grid-area: third; 
  background-image: url("https://magicezy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Lifestyle-2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.item4 { grid-area: fourth; }
.item5 { grid-area: fifth; }
.item6 { 
  grid-area: sixth; 
  background-image: url("https://magicezy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Home-and-Living-2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.item7 { grid-area: seventh; }
.item8 { 
  grid-area: eight;
  background-image: url("https://magicezy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Cars-and-Boats-1-1.jpg");
  background-size: cover; 
}

.item3, .item4{ 
  height: 299px;
}

.item5, .item6, .item7, .item8{ 
  height: 391px;
}

.grid-container {
  font-family: 'roboto', 'sens-serif';
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'first first second second'
    'first first second second'
    'first first third fourth'
    'fifth sixth seventh eight';
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 19.7% 30.3%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  position:relative;
}

.home-category-title
{
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 750;
}

.home-category-content
{
    font-size: 18.5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.item3 {
  position: relative;
}

.home-category-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.grid-container .item-3:hover .home-category-overlay {
  opacity: .5;
}

.item3:hover .home-category-overlay,
.item6:hover .home-category-overlay,
.item8:hover .home-category-overlay{
  opacity: .5;
}

.home-category-content-overlay {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 22%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item1">
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
            <div class="home-category-overlay">
                <div class="home-category-content-overlay">Lifestyle</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item4">
            <h3 class="home-category-title">LIFESTYLE</h3>
            <div class="home-category-content">
                Uncover the latest technology that perfectly blends with your everyday needs. May it be DIY scratch
                repairs or future innovations.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item5">
            <h3 class="home-category-title">HOME & LIVING</h3>
            <div class="home-category-content">
                Wonder in awe of MagicEzy’s surface repair kits made to make DIY floor, tile, appearance, or even
                kitchen & bathroom repairs look pro
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item6">
            <div class="home-category-overlay">
                <div class="home-category-content-overlay">Home & Living</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item7">
            <h3 class="home-category-title">CARS & <p>BOATS</h3>
            <div class="home-category-content">
                Explore MagicEzy’s top of the line DIY scratch removers, non-drip paint chip repair kits, fiberglass and
                gelcoat boat repair kit ready to sail & journey with you
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item8">
            <div class="home-category-overlay">
                <div class="home-category-content-overlay">Cars & Boats</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: oh my word, guy! thank you! I've been at this for far too long! That solved it! Thanks again, cheers!